# Git bash and x-win32 will work together for running linux applications remotely?

Tags: linux, git, putty

usually, school recommends using PuTTY with X-win32 to access and run linux software remotely on a window machine. 
PuTTY is basically a tool to SSH into the linux machine from my understanding. Since I need to use github on my windows as well, git packages its own bash shell as a whole of git, so can it work with x-win32? I dont want to have two bash shell running just for convenience.
If it does, how to set it up? Anything different from setting up Putty? 
Thanks!

Comment: It should work; you'll just have to start the X forwarding session from the bash shell that's provided - e.g. `DISPLAY=localhost:0.0 ssh -X <remotehost>` should accomplish the ssh session, then you can launch the remote applications from the other end. The only setup difference would be that the ssh key (if you're using one) will be in a different form than putty uses - you can convert the key using `puttygen` so that it's in a form that's suitable for use with the command line ssh.

Comment: acutally i just tried them together. Fresh git bash and xwin32. I run xwin32 frist, and then opened the bash input ssh -X <remote>. when i test to open a file with gedit, it says Could not find ':' in DISPLAY: needs-to-be-defined

(gedit:7038): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: localhost:13.0